# Build NodeJS module for meteor.com platform

Tags: node.js, meteor, npm

I'm using MeteorJS 0.6.1 and the NPM Integration.

For a meteor application, I need to use a NodeJS module [node-time](https://github.com/TooTallNate/node-time).
This module needs to be build to run. On my computer it's working, but it's build for the local platform : Mac OS..

When I do a "**meteor deploy mysite.meteor.com**", I get the following error on the meteor.com cloud :

> INFO Error:
>   /meteor/containers/xxx-yyy/bundle/app/packages/time/node_modules/time/build/Release/time.node:
>   invalid ELF header

I guess the problem is, meteor.com is not the same platform as my mac.

So the question is,
How can I "prepare" / "build" / "configure" my application to be able to run on the meteor.com platform.

PS : [Meteor 0.6.0: brand new distribution system, app packages, NPM integration](http://meteor.com/blog/2013/04/04/meteor-060-brand-new-distribution-system-app-packages-npm-integration) :

> If the NPM module has architecture-specific binary components, bundles
>   built with meteor bundle or meteor deploy will contain the components
>   as built for the developer’s platform and may not run on other
>   platforms.

Comment: I guess meteor.com platform is some linux distro because it's hosted on AWS. But you can ask developers at meteor-talk@googlegroups